# Interpreting wildcards (eg, * and &) in SOSL queries through the API. Escape or not?

Tags: sosl, ajax, ajax-toolkit, escape, dynamic-sosl

I have a search feature that is implemented with the AJAX toolkit to use SOSL.

```
var results = sforce.connection.search("FIND {" + sanitize(...) + "} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ...");
```

The `sanitize(...)` function escapes SOSL-reserved characters (below) according to [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#topic-title) by inserting backslashes so that they are interpreted by SOSL as literal characters.

```
? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -
```

Because the documentation instructs to escape the above special characters, the user now loses the ability to use the `*` and `?` wildcards (e.g., if the user enters `amer*`, the `sanitize` would convert it to `amer\*`)

This now brings me to a few questions,

- Should the `*` and `?` wildcards be exposed to the user, ie. unescaped?
- How can the implementation distinguish if the user intends to use a literal asterisk from a wildcard search?

Answer (score 1):

From the SOSL [Wildcards](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#i1423049) documentation:

> Asterisks match zero or more characters at the middle or end (not the beginning) of your search term. For example, a search for `john*` finds items that start with `john`, such as, `john`, `johnson`, or `johnny`. A search for mi* meyers finds items with *mike meyers* or *michael meyers*. **If you are searching for a literal asterisk in a word or phrase, then escape the asterisk (precede it with the `\` character)**.

So I'd say it is expected that you only escape the `*` if you want the literal value.

It would probably be easiest to let the users escape the * character if required. Of have a "With Wildcards" option next to the search input to toggle if you do full escaping or not.